# Export Metadata from command line

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to bulk export the metadata and table definition from SQL Server using the command line? I know we can do this using SQL Server Management studio, but hoping to automate this across a huge volume of databases.

Thanks in advance,
Simak

Comment: did you know bcp Utility??

Comment: ofcourse @Ganesh_Devlekar, but i'm not looking for the data. just the metadata and table definition. Thanks!

Comment: This link might help you http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/script-table-definitions-using-tsql/